# how to clearTimeout call within SetTimeout Loop condition

Tags: javascript, webview, settimeout, cleartimeout

i have an task to load multiple url in webpage. For i have array size of 10 url links but i have to navigate oly 5 URl out of it, i set Timeout for every page load one after another and load next. When its reaches 5th url i have to visit my home page but since my Array count is 10 its keep on loading 10 times 
here my sample code for your reference :

```
for (var i = 0; i < urlResult.length; i++) {
    myVar = setTimeout(function(y) {
        if (urlResult[y] == lastUrl) {
            wait(5000)
            if (pageVist_num == Total_count) {
                console.log("cleat timeout")
                clearTimeout(myVar);
                document.getElementById("web").src = 'https://www.google.com/'
            } else {
                pageVist_num = pageVist_num + 1
                document.getElementById("web").loadURL(lastUrl);
            }
        } else {
            if (pageVist_num == Total_count) {
                clearTimeout(myVar);
                console.log("clear timeout")
                document.getElementById("web").src = 'https://www.google.com/'
            } else {
                pageVist_num = pageVist_num + 1
                document.getElementById("web").loadURL(urlResult[y]);
            }
        }
    }, i * 18000, i); // we're passing x
}
```

Comment: Your code will only hold last reference. Use an array to hold all references and based on index, fetch necessary ref and clear it

Comment: im new to javascript i dono can u solve this ?

Comment: its loading all urls one after another perfectly but the thing is i cant break the loop when i want to exit

Comment: sorry. Got stuck. Can you create a fiddle so we update it? I'll also look for any reference material that might help you